# Domain shared session prevents authentication

Tags: symfony

I'm using symfony2 and its login system through security.yml
When I log in with correct credentials , I get redirected to the correct page but will still have the anonymous in the profiler bar.
when I remove this line :

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');
```

it works.
I need that line because my socket server is running on domain.com and I'm developing on sub.domain.com
How can I fix this problem ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your cookie domain in the framework configuration, instead of calling `ini_set()`:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: .domain.com
```

Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-domain

Comment: The token is still anonymous

Comment: Ok let me fix my sayings, when I changed domain.com to .domain.com it worked ^^